# How to prevent execution of runnables when one of them throws exception

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I have a set of elements and for each of them I'm executing method, by passing it to CompletableFuture.runAsync() as Runnable. During execution, there may be a need to stop whole calculations, so I check some condition before execution of method. If calculations should be stopped, then I throw an exception, which is handled outside of CompletableFuture. I would like to prevent execution of all Runnables, which are executed after exception was thrown. So, in other words, I don't want to wait for all CompletableFutures to complete, when any of them throws an exception.

```
Set elements = ...
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N);
try {
    CompletableFuture.allOf(elements.stream().map(e - > CompletableFuture.runAsync(() - > {
        if (shouldStop()) {
            throw new MyException();
        }
        myMethod(e);
    }, executor)).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join()
} catch (CompletionException e) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cancel all of them when an exception occurs. The obstacles are that you are not knowing all of them when creating them and that you don’t want to do this work more than once. This can be solved by creating a new, empty `CompletableFuture` first (let’s call it `f1`). Then, create the futures as before, but insert a call to `f1.cancel` in the `if(shouldStop()) { … }` statement. Then, after all futures have been created, chain an action that will cancel all of them to the `f1` future.

The cancellation will serve both purposes, It will prevent the execution of runnables which have not started yet and it will make the future returned by `allOf` not wait for the completion of still ongoing evaluations.

Since cancelling a `CompletableFuture` is not different to completing it exceptionally with a `CancellationException` and in case of multiple exceptions, the future returned by `allOf` will report an arbitrary one, we may use `completeExceptionally` with the custom `MyException` instead, to ensure that the reported exception will not be a secondary `CancellationException`.

A self contained example would be:

```
static final AtomicInteger STOP = new AtomicInteger(2);
static boolean shouldStop() {
    return STOP.getAndDecrement() <= 0;
}
static final int N = 10;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> elements = IntStream.range(0, 100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N);
    try {
        CompletableFuture<?> cancelAll = new CompletableFuture<>();
        CompletableFuture<?>[] all = elements.stream()
            .map(e ->
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                    System.out.println("entered "+e);
                    if(shouldStop()) {
                        RuntimeException myException = new RuntimeException("stopped");
                         // alternatively cancelAll.cancel(false);
                        cancelAll.completeExceptionally(myException);
                        throw myException;
                    }
                    System.out.println("processing "+e);
                }, executor))
            .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new);
        cancelAll.whenComplete((value,throwable) -> {
            if(throwable != null) {
                for(CompletableFuture<?> cf: all) cf.completeExceptionally(throwable);
            }
        });
        CompletableFuture.allOf(all).join();
    } catch (CompletionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

which will print something like

```
entered 3
entered 8
entered 4
entered 6
entered 1
entered 9
entered 0
entered 7
entered 5
entered 2
entered 10
processing 8
processing 3
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: stopped
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:346)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$BiRelay.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1423)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$CoCompletion.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
    at CompletableFutureTest.lambda$main$3(CompletableFutureTest.java:34)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
    at CompletableFutureTest.lambda$main$0(CompletableFutureTest.java:26)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: stopped
    at CompletableFutureTest.lambda$main$0(CompletableFutureTest.java:25)
    ... 4 more
```

showing that due to the concurrency, some of the runnables are already running but no subsequent execution will be started once the cancellation has been propagated.

Note that since the `cancelAll` will only be completed exceptionally or never at all, you could simplify the chained action to `cancelAll.whenComplete((value,throwable) -> { for(CompletableFuture<?> cf: all) cf.completeExceptionally(throwable); });` but it’s just a matter of coding style whether to keep the redundant check or not.

You may also add a delay to the processing step to see that `allOf(all).join()` won’t wait for completion if the stop condition has been fulfilled.

It’s also possible to chain an action to the futures returned by `runAsync` which will cancel all of them on any exceptional completion, not just the explicit stopping. But then, care must be taken to return the original future representing the operation scheduled via `runAsync` instead of the future returned by `whenComplete`.

```
CompletableFuture<?> cancelAll = new CompletableFuture<>();
CompletableFuture<?>[] all = elements.stream()
    .map(e -> {
        CompletableFuture<Void> cf = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            System.out.println("entered "+e);
            if(shouldStop()) throw new RuntimeException("stopped");
            System.out.println("processing "+e);
        }, executor);
        cf.whenComplete((value,throwable) -> {
            if(throwable != null) cancelAll.completeExceptionally(throwable);
        });
        return cf;
    })
    .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new);
cancelAll.whenComplete((value,throwable) -> {
    for(CompletableFuture<?> cf: all) cf.completeExceptionally(throwable);
});
CompletableFuture.allOf(all).join();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much (well any!) experience with `CompletableFuture`s but I do have a suggestion (may be of help?)
Can you declare the lambda within the `CompletableFuture.allOf(elements.stream().map` outside the try block. This way non of the futures get run, until inside the try. but they are still accessible to the catch block. Within that you can then `cancel` all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you should do is `interrupt` all the running tasks you want to terminate faster, which means that these tasks may need to check for interrupts so they can know to stop what they were doing and terminate faster.

Additionally, rather than waiting for the interrupted tasks to actually terminate you can continue in the main thread and let them terminate in the background.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> elements = Arrays.asList(5, null, 6, 3, 4); // these elements will fail fast
    // List<Integer> elements = Arrays.asList(5, 2, 6, 3, 4); // these elements will succeed

    try {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(elements.size());
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(elements.size());
        elements.stream().forEach(e -> {
            executor.execute(() -> {
                try {
                    doSomething(e);
                    latch.countDown();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // shutdown executor ASAP on exception, read the docs for `shutdownNow()`
                    // it will interrupt all tasks in the executor
                    if (!executor.isShutdown()) {
                        executor.shutdownNow();
                    }
                    for (int i = (int) latch.getCount(); i >= 0; i--) {
                        latch.countDown();
                    }
                    // log the exception
                    ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                }
            });
        });
        latch.await();
        if (executor.isShutdown()) {
            System.out.println("Tasks failed! Terminating remaining tasks in the background.");
        } else {
            executor.shutdown();
            System.out.println("Tasks succeeded!");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void doSomething(Integer sleepSecs) {
    // You will want to check for `interrupted()` throughout the method you want to be able to cancel
    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " interrupted early");
        return;
    }

    if (sleepSecs == null) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " throwing exception ");
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    try {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " started interruptable sleep for " + sleepSecs + "s");
        Thread.sleep(sleepSecs * 1000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " finished interruptable sleep" + sleepSecs + "s");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " interrupted sleep!");
    }

    // ...possibly some part of the task that can't be skipped, such as cleanup

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " complete!");
}
```